# Angular JS / Data Binding / Controller

Tags: data-binding, angularjs

I have two controllers and one service. Could someone explain me why
firstname will be not updatet / the reference is "old" when changing it?

I thought this is the way to communicate between controllers...?

```
<!-- language: lang-js --> 
// Controller 1
function controllerOne (..., myService) {
    $scope.firstname = myService.customer.firstname;
}

// Controller 2
function controllerTwo (..., myService) {
    $scope.firstnameNew = myService.customer.firstname;
}

// Service
application.factory('myService', ...)
    function(...) {
    return {
         customer: {
             "firstname": "",
             "lastname": "",
             "pers": "",
             "street": "",
             "zip": "",
             "city": "",
             "selectedCountry": "",
             "comment": ""                          
        },
                    ...
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Communicating between controllers, please check the below fiddle.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.message = '';

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
        this.message = msg;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
});

function ControllerZero($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
        sharedService.prepForBroadcast(msg);
    };

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = sharedService.message;
    });        
}

function ControllerOne($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = 'ONE: ' + sharedService.message;
    });        
}

function ControllerTwo($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        $scope.message = 'TWO: ' + sharedService.message;
    });
}

ControllerZero.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];        

ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];

ControllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

Answer (score 0):

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">    
<div data-ng-controller="ctrl1">
        {{firstName}}
        {{lastName}}
    </div>
      <div data-ng-controller="ctrl2">
        {{firstName}}
        {{lastName}}
    </div>
</body>
Script :
         var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.firstName = myService.firstName;
    $scope.lastName = myService.lastName;
    myService.firstName = "ABC";
    myService.lastName = "DEF";
});
myApp.controller('ctrl2', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.firstName = myService.firstName;
    $scope.lastName = myService.lastName;
});
myApp.factory('myService', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        firstName: '123',
        lastName: '456'
    };
});
```